# Google Maps API store locator issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm learning PHP and MySQL. I was trying the tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?hl=en

The query in the code seems to be coming back empty. I have a table in my database setup as per the instructions. Using echo calls I have confirmed that I am getting a valid db connection, all variables are being called correctly. If I run a basic db query on that table (i.e. without any of the math or sprint), I get the rows returned from the table. The "base2.php" file contains only the 3 items as per the tutorial (dbname, username and password), these are correct.  So when I load the page from the localhost using the required URL syntax:

```
pagename.php?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25
```

I only get a blank page with the xml header.  As I said, using echo's, I have confirmed that the script is getting as far as the query, which is being returned as empty. Has anyone played with this tutorial and found any issues?  I get the same results using IE11, Chrome and FF. I'm using WAMPserver v2.4, PHP 5.4.12, MySQL 5.6.12 and Apache 2.4.4.  The table in the db has the correct rows and values and has data in it.

```
<?php require "base2.php";

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the stores table
$query = sprintf("SELECT Name, Address, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos(     radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("Name", $row['Name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("Address", $row['Address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: If the query returns empty, did you try to remove the `HAVING` clause, so it will at least show what distance it calculates?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. When I remove the HAVING clause, I indeed get a result, all rows return and include the distance attribute and the XML is created. What does this mean though?

Comment: It means they are further away then you think apparently... What does it say the distance is? Also, don't use _strings_ if you mean _numbers_, `distance < '%s'` looks weird, that should probably be `distance < %d` or `distance < %f`.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. The distances returning in the rows are all around 4471.702953429536.  the '%s' is what was provided by the google development site as part the sprintf(), it doesn't seem to make any difference if I change them to %d.

Comment: Well, that means their lat/long coordinates are quite a long way away ;) Double check your database with those coordinates...

Comment: Yeah will do. Thanks for the help, I think that with your assistance I've been able to nut this one out. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

you must consider the international ASCII charater on this line 
header("Content-type: text/xml");
to be like this way
header("Content-type: text/xml charset=utf-8");
then xml file will be generated